# Play Framework Scala 2.2.2 store multiple values to session

Tags: scala, session-variables, playframework-2.2

I would like to store user role to session. How I need to do this in play framework + scala?

My authentication method looks like this:

```
val loginForm = Form(
    tuple(
      "email" -> text,
      "password" -> text
    ) verifying ("Invalid username or password", result => result match {
      case (email, password) => User.authenticate(email, new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encode(md.digest(password.getBytes)).toString()).isDefined
    })
  )

 def authenticate = Action { implicit request =>
    loginForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
      formWithErrors => BadRequest(html.authentication.login(formWithErrors)),
      user => Redirect(routes.Application.index).withSession("username" -> user._1)
    )
  }
```

And my usermode looks like this:

```
  val simple = {
    get[Long]("user.id") ~
      get[String]("user.firstname") ~
      get[String]("user.lastname") ~
      get[String]("user.password") ~
      get[String]("user.email") ~
      get[Long] ("user.role") ~
      get[Long]("user.companyId") map {
      case id~firstname~lastname~password~email~role~companyId => User(id, firstname, lastname, password, email, role, companyId)
    }
  }
```

Comment: Regarding your particular case, how about using SecureSocial? http://securesocial.ws/

Comment: Good point. I would still like to be able store some valuse from user model to session though :D

Comment: just add them as key-value pairs to your session, like you did with username. Though I don't see username anywhere in your code. Does it compile?

Comment: Yes it does work. Username seems to be stuck there. And correct if I'm wrong, but doesn't the values come from the loginForm object?